# Is it possible to make homemade mascarpone?

Tags: mascarpone

I had a piece of tiramisu that had a layer of mascarpone that really balanced the other flavors out perfectly.  At the grocery store it's sold in such little/expensive containers I was looking for an alternative homemade version - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You'll require heavy cream, an acid (vinegar or tartaric acid), au bain marie technique and patience and a refridgerator.

[Check out preparation here.](http://www.heavenlytiramisu.com/mascarpo.htm)

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://biology.clc.uc.edu/fankhauser/Cheese/mascarpone.HTM) are some fairly complete, although fairly long, instructions for making homemade Marscapone.

Any cream cheese (such as Philadelphia) could make a reasonable substitute, with extra cream added if necessary.